# How do I make JOOQ codegen work with Oracle Edition-Based Redefinition?

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I'm working on a project with an Oracle database where we have decided to enable [Edition based redefinition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_editions.htm#ADFNS020). We're also using jooq-codegen for creating Java objects based on objects we have created in the database.

I have read through the [documentation for jooq-codegen](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/), but have issues finding a way to make JOOQ work with Oracle editions. Normally I would use an `alter session set edition=<some edition>` statement to connect to the correct edition, but I can't find a way to do this with jooq-codegen.

Is there any way to do init queries with jooq-codegen, or maybe even a way to specify an edition with jooq-codegen? I'm hoping there is something I have overlooked as I can't find this in the documentation.

I don't think it should matter, but I'm using maven and this will be ran in Jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting case where it might be beneficial to be able to run additional SQL statements after a JDBC connection has been initialised by the code generator. Probably worth a [feature request you could report here](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose).

As a workaround, you can always:

- Extend the `OracleDatabase` from the jOOQ-meta module and override the `create0()` method, which provides an initialised `DSLContext` for all of your code generation meta queries.
- Use a [programmatic code generation configuration](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic/) and initialise the JDBC connection yourself before passing it to the code generator